# Error in creating an app in ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, dependencies, command-line-interface

I have just started ionic and wanted to start creating an app, but it gives me the following error while installing cordova dependecies:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/asc# ionic start app1
? What starter would you like to use: conference
? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and
 Android? Yes
✔ Creating directory ./app1 - done!
[INFO] Fetching app base
       (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
✔ Downloading - done!
[INFO] Fetching starter template conference
       (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/archive/master.tar.gz)
✔ Downloading - done!
✔ Updating package.json with app details - done!
✔ Creating configuration file ionic.config.json - done!
[INFO] Installing dependencies may take several minutes!
> npm install
✖ Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1):

        npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
        npm ERR! sha1-3hnuc77yGrPAdAo3sz22JGS6ves= integrity checksum failed
        when using sha1: wanted sha1-3hnuc77yGrPAdAo3sz22JGS6ves= but got
        sha1-ZON8WQs6HaRM5U/GT5PKi7Nbgfg=. (4998 bytes)

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR! /root/.npm/_logs/2017-08-10T15_04_19_085Z-debug.log
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: try  `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: @mohamad-rabee your comment did the magic man! thanks a ton!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm cache clean --force
```

This one did the magic!